# Activate default tabs based on condition

Tags: codeigniter, tabs, defaulttablemodel

I have the following code a page that holds 3 tabs as follow:

```
<div id="tab-container">
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Wall', this, '#F06078')" id="defaultOpen">Wall</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Profile', this, '#F06078')">Profile</button>     
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Gallery', this, '#F06078')">Gallery</button>
```

The idea is to make whatever tab that's called on from a controller the default and land on it. I try passing $data to the page but it's telling me it's undefined. I also think maybe storing the info in a session and calling it on the page where the tabs are, but I'm not that flexible yet with the coding.

```
function index ($page='wall') {         

$data['defaultOpen'] = 'wall';
$data['images_model'] = $this->images_model->get_images();          

$this->load->view($page, $data);            
        }
```

I know the codes are not all there right now, but hopefully you get the idea. I will probably need to use an IF statement either in php/js and I was hoping someone might give me some feedback on that. Thanks in advance for all input.

Comment: Where you are trying to show the default tab?

Comment: @DanishAli The view is a page with 3 tabs: wall, profile, gallery. What I'd like is have the related tab open as default based on the controller. If the controller is related to the wall, the "wall" tab should be default. If the controller is related to the gallery to upload images, I'd like the landing tab to be "gallery". Right now if I'm in the gallery tab and I refresh the page, it goes back to the wall tab.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
// controller
public function index ($page = 'wall') {

    // pass the selected data to view
    $data['selectedPage'] = $page;
    $data['images_model'] = $this->images_model->get_images();

    $this->load->view('viewName', $data);  

}

// view

// use ternary operator to set active class to tab
// example:
// <?php echo $selectedPage== 'wall' ? 'active' : '' ?>
// code above means if $selectedPage equals 'wall', set class to active,
// if not do nothing
<button class="tablink <?php echo $selectedPage== 'wall' ? 'active' : '' ?>" 
   onclick="openPage('Wall', this, '#F06078')"id="defaultOpen">Wall</button>
<button class="tablink <?php echo $selectedPage== 'profile' ? 'active' : '' ?>" 
   onclick="openPage('Profile', this, 
 '#F06078')">Profile</button>     
<button class="tablink <?php echo $selectedPage== 'gallery' ? 'active' : '' ?>" 
   onclick="openPage('Gallery', this, 
 '#F06078')">Gallery</button>
```

Comment: Hi could you check your code again. There's a syntax error in the view as follow: 

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?>' in C:\wamp64\

Comment: I've fixed it now, I forgot to echo and my ternary operator had syntax error,it should be ok now.

Comment: Thanks but still nothing. No errors but it still defaults to the "wall" tab after login even if I set selected tab to "gallery". Maybe we have to do something with the id=defaultOpen. I notice if make id=<?php $defaultOpen ?> or $selectedTab it still defaults to the wall, but it doesn't highlight it like before; which may indicate we're still missing something. But thank you anyway for your input!

Comment: You shoud probably remove the defaultOpen id, and replace IT with a class Like i did in my answer. Ids Are used      for targeting and styling individual elements, you need to apply the same behaviour to multiple elements, classes Are used for that.

Comment: By the way. You didn't ask but I forgot to mention the following  js code: 

document.getElementById('defaultOpen').click();

That's the code that click on the tab to open. So now I'm trying to see if I can create an IF statement to make that work. If you can think of anything, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: You should probalby use document.getElementsByClassName('active').click() instead, like I've said, if you need to apply the same behaviour to multiple elements, you need classes. Also don't forget to apply any styling and effects you have for the id in css.

Answer (score 0):

controller :

```
public function index ($page = 'wall') {
     $this->load->helper('url'); // only if you haven't load helper in autoload.
     $data['images_model'] = $this->images_model->get_images();
     $this->load->view('viewName', $data);
}
```

view :

```
<?php $active_tab = end($this->uri->segment_array());?>
<button class="tablink<?php echo ($active_tab == 'wall')? ' active':''; ?>" onclick="openPage('Wall', this, '#F06078')" id="defaultOpen">Wall</button>
<button class="tablink<?php echo ($active_tab == 'profile')? ' active':''; ?>" onclick="openPage('Profile', this, '#F06078')">Profile</button>     
<button class="tablink<?php echo ($active_tab == 'gallery')? ' active':''; ?>" onclick="openPage('Gallery', this, '#F06078')">Gallery</button>
```

Comment: Thanks but this is the error I get with your code:      

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Runtime Notice

Message: Only variables should be passed by reference

Answer (score 0):

The first method is to use **parameters** in the URL like `http://localhost/example.com/home?tab=wall`

Then use this URL parameter to active your tab

```
$tab = $this->input->get('tab'); //wall
<button class="tablink <?php if($tab == 'wall'){ echo 'active';}?>" onclick="openPage('Wall', this, '#F06078')" id="defaultOpen">Wall</button>
```

Apply same for other tabs as well

The second method is to pas variable to view. Use variable not a parameter in a function

```
function index() {         
  $data['defaultOpen'] = 'wall';
  $data['images_model'] = $this->images_model->get_images();          
  $this->load->view($page, $data);            
}
```

Use `$defaultOpen` like this

```
<button class="tablink <?php if($defaultOpen == 'wall'){ echo 'active';}?>" onclick="openPage('Wall', this, '#F06078')" id="defaultOpen">Wall</button>
```

Comment: Hi Danish. In method 1 it says that $tab is undefined. Method 2  doesn't do anything. It keeps defaulting to the "wall" tab after login even though I pass 'gallery' as $defaultOpen to the view.

Comment: Maybe we have to do something with the id=defaultOpen. I notice if make id=<?php $defaultOpen ?> it still defaults to the wall, but it doesn't highlight it like before; which may indicate we're still missing something. But thank you anyway for your input!

Comment: By the way. You didn't ask but I forgot to mention the following  js code: 

document.getElementById('defaultOpen').click();

That's the code that clicks on the tab to open. So now I'm trying to see if I can create an IF statement to make that work. If you can think of anything, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @dreamerdan Also you didn't add `openPage()` in your question as well.